# Excluir uma linha especifica de uma tabela html com jquery

Tags: jquery

Como excluir a linha dessa tabela:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th>Cod.</th><th>Nome</th><th></th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="tbl1" data-id="1"><td>1</td><td>João</td><td><a href="#" class="excluir" data-id=1/>EXCLUIR</a></td></tr>
<tr class="tbl1" data-id="2"><td>1</td><td>Ronaldo</td><td><a href="#" class="excluir" data-id=2/>EXCLUIR</a></td></tr>
<tr class="tbl1" data-id="3"><td>1</td><td>Silvia</td><td><a href="#" class="excluir" data-id=3/>EXCLUIR</a></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Por exemplo a linha da tabela id=2  ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pra remover dinamicamente você pode fazer:

```js
$(".excluir").click(function() {
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Cod.</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>João</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="excluir">EXCLUIR</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>Ronaldo</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="excluir">EXCLUIR</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>Silvia</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="excluir">EXCLUIR</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
$('[data-id="2"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

Para excluir uma linha da tabela pelo seu id:

```
$('#iddalinha').hide();
```

Mas no seu caso o id que você pretende é um atributo data:

```
$('tr[data-id="iddalinha"]').hide();
```